# Djangoで作成したWebアプリをherokuでデプロイすると失敗します。

Tags: django, heroku

Djangoで作成したWebアプリをherokuでデプロイするため

```
git push heroku main
```

を実行したところ、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
"""略"""

remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/hogehoge.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hogehoge.git'
```

いろいろ調べると以下のような記事を発見し
試してみたのですが、それでも同じエラーがでます。

[【Django】herokuデプロイ時に遭遇したエラー その① - Qiita](https://qiita.com/nissy7ok/items/716cc6e973104c6d660d)

その他、足りないものはどのようなものが考えられますでしょうか？

Comment: 他のページにリンクする際は、「誰が書いたか」よりも「何が書いてあるのか」ページの内容が分かるようにリンクを貼ると読み手に取って親切かと思います。 / 回答の方もリンク先が万一消えてしまう場合に備えて、(まったく同じ操作で解決したのであっても) ポイントとなる箇所を引用するなどして、あなたの投稿で自己完結した状態になっていることが望ましいです。

Answer (score 0):

下記のリンクと同じものが原因でした。同じ操作をしたところ解決しました！

[HerokuにPython Djangoをデプロイするときエラー「No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6...」 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/mizoe@github/items/0f7898fe026fa4cefe9d)